# Stellar and gaseous surface mass density spiral galaxies

Tags: galaxy, dark-matter, stellar-astrophysics

I have a database with more than 1000 rotation curves of spiral and lenticular galaxies (xxx-gxx notation is ESOxxx-G0xx). I am working on dark matter mass modeling and I would like to know whether someone knows or not where to find their stellar and gaseous surface mass densities. I don't pretend to find all of them, but the largest amount possible, in order to accumulate significant statistics.

Thanks in advance.

```
1-g7
10-g4
101-g20
101-g5
102-g10
102-g15
102-g7
103-g13
103-g39
105-g20
105-g3
106-g12
106-g8
107-g24
107-g36
108-g13
108-g19
108-g6
109-g32
111-g9
112-g10
113-g21
114-g21
116-g12
116-g14
117-g18
117-g19
120-g16
121-g26
121-g6
122-g11
123-g15
123-g16
123-g23
123-g9
124-g15
140-g1
140-g24
140-g25
140-g28
140-g34
140-g40
141-g20
141-g23
141-g37
141-g9
142-g30
142-g34
142-g35
143-g6
143-g8
145-g18
145-g22
146-g6
151-g30
155-g6
157-g20
162-g15
162-g17
163-g11
163-g14
18-g13
181-g2
183-g14
183-g5
184-g51
184-g54
184-g60
184-g63
184-g67
184-g74
184-g8
185-g11
185-g36
185-g68
185-g70
186-g21
186-g75
186-g8
187-g51
187-g6
187-g8
196-g11
197-g2
197-g24
200-g3
202-g26
202-g35
204-g19
205-g2
206-g14
208-g31
21-g3
215-g39
216-g21
216-g8
219-g14
22-g3
220-g8
231-g11
231-g23
231-g29
231-g6
233-g36
233-g41
233-g42
233-g47
234-g13
234-g32
235-g14
235-g16
235-g20
236-g37
237-g49
238-g24
239-g17
240-g11
240-g13
242-g18
243-g36
243-g8
244-g31
244-g43
245-g10
249-g16
249-g35
25-g16
250-g17
251-g10
251-g6
264-g43
264-g48
265-g16
266-g15
266-g8
267-g29
267-g38
268-g11
268-g33
269-g15
269-g19
269-g48
269-g61
269-g75
269-g78
269-g82
27-g17
27-g24
271-g22
271-g4
273-g6
281-g38
282-g3
284-g13
284-g21
284-g24
284-g29
284-g39
285-g1
285-g27
285-g40
286-g16
286-g18
287-g13
289-g10
290-g22
291-g10
296-g25
296-g26
297-g37
298-g16
298-g29
298-g36
298-g8
299-g18
299-g4
3-g3
3-g4
302-g12
302-g9
303-g14
304-g16
305-g14
305-g6
305-g9
306-g2
306-g32
308-g23
309-g17
309-g5
31-g18
31-g5
310-g2
317-g32
317-g52
317-g53
319-g16
32-g18
320-g26
321-g1
321-g10
321-g17
322-g33
322-g36
322-g45
322-g48
322-g55
322-g93
323-g27
323-g33
323-g41
323-g42
325-g27
325-g50
327-g27
328-g15
328-g3
328-g41
328-g43
328-g46
329-g7
33-g22
33-g32
336-g13
336-g6
337-g22
337-g6
338-g22
339-g36
34-g12
34-g3
340-g26
340-g8
342-g43
343-g18
343-g28
346-g1
346-g14
346-g26
347-g28
347-g33
347-g34
349-g32
349-g33
35-g18
35-g3
350-g17
350-g23
351-g1
351-g18
352-g14
352-g15
352-g24
352-g27
352-g50
352-g53
353-g14
353-g2
353-g26
354-g17
354-g46
354-g47
355-g26
356-g15
356-g18
357-g19
357-g3
358-g17
358-g58
358-g63
358-g9
36-g19
361-g12
362-g11
363-g23
365-g28
365-g31
366-g4
366-g9
373-g12
373-g21
373-g29
374-g10
374-g11
374-g26
374-g27
374-g29
374-g3
374-g49
374-g8
375-g12
375-g2
375-g26
375-g29
375-g47
375-g60
376-g2
377-g10
377-g11
377-g31
378-g11
379-g6
38-g12
380-g14
380-g19
380-g2
380-g24
381-g51
382-g32
382-g4
382-g58
383-g2
383-g55
383-g67
383-g88
385-g8
386-g43
386-g44
386-g6
386-g9
387-g20
387-g26
387-g4
398-g20
399-g23
4-g19
40-g12
400-g21
400-g37
400-g5
401-g3
403-g16
403-g31
404-g18
404-g31
404-g45
405-g5
406-g26
406-g33
41-g6
410-g19
410-g27
411-g10
411-g3
412-g21
413-g14
413-g16
413-g23
414-g25
415-g10
415-g15
415-g28
415-g31
416-g20
416-g33
416-g37
416-g41
417-g18
418-g1
418-g8
419-g3
419-g4
42-g10
42-g3
420-g3
422-g10
422-g12
422-g23
425-g18
426-g8
427-g14
427-g2
43-g8
433-g10
433-g15
433-g17
434-g23
435-g10
435-g14
435-g24
435-g34
435-g50
435-g51
436-g39
437-g22
437-g25
437-g31
437-g35
437-g47
437-g54
437-g69
438-g15
438-g18
439-g11
439-g18
439-g20
439-g9
44-g1
440-g51
441-g11
441-g2
442-g2
442-g24
443-g38
443-g41
443-g59
443-g80
444-g1
444-g14
444-g21
444-g33
444-g47
444-g84
444-g86
445-g15
445-g19
445-g26
445-g39
446-g1
446-g18
446-g2
446-g23
446-g44
446-g51
446-g53
446-g58
447-g21
447-g23
448-g13
452-g8
459-g14
459-g6
46-g8
460-g25
460-g29
460-g31
460-g8
461-g10
461-g25
461-g3
461-g44
462-g16
463-g25
466-g13
466-g27
466-g28
466-g5
467-g23
467-g27
467-g36
468-g11
468-g23
469-g22
471-g2
472-g10
474-g39
474-g5
476-g15
476-g16
476-g25
477-g16
477-g18
478-g11
48-g8
481-g11
481-g13
481-g2
482-g1
482-g16
482-g2
482-g35
482-g41
482-g43
482-g46
483-g12
483-g2
483-g6
484-g25
485-g12
485-g24
485-g4
487-g19
487-g2
488-g44
488-g54
489-g11
489-g47
489-g6
490-g10
490-g14
490-g28
490-g36
490-g45
496-g19
497-g14
497-g18
497-g2
497-g34
498-g3
499-g22
499-g39
499-g4
501-g1
501-g11
501-g68
501-g75
501-g86
501-g97
502-g12
502-g13
502-g2
505-g8
506-g4
507-g11
507-g2
507-g56
507-g62
507-g7
508-g11
508-g60
509-g35
509-g45
509-g74
509-g80
509-g91
51-g18
511-g46
512-g12
512-g5
514-g10
515-g13
515-g3
516-g8
527-g11
527-g19
527-g21
528-g17
528-g34
53-g2
530-g34
531-g22
532-g14
533-g4
533-g48
533-g53
533-g6
533-g8
534-g24
534-g3
534-g31
534-g9
535-g15
536-g17
539-g14
539-g5
54-g21
540-g10
540-g16
541-g1
541-g4
543-g12
544-g27
544-g32
545-g11
545-g21
545-g5
546-g15
546-g29
546-g31
546-g36
546-g37
547-g1
547-g14
547-g2
547-g24
547-g31
547-g32
547-g4
548-g31
548-g32
548-g50
548-g63
548-g71
548-g77
549-g18
549-g22
549-g40
55-g29
550-g7
551-g13
551-g31
552-g43
553-g26
553-g3
554-g10
554-g19
554-g24
554-g29
554-g34
555-g16
555-g2
555-g29
556-g12
556-g23
556-g5
562-g14
563-g11
563-g13
563-g14
563-g17
563-g21
563-g28
564-g20
564-g23
564-g31
564-g35
564-g36
566-g14
566-g22
566-g26
566-g30
566-g9
567-g26
567-g45
567-g6
568-g19
569-g22
57-g80
570-g2
571-g12
571-g16
572-g18
572-g22
573-g14
573-g6
574-g28
574-g33
576-g11
576-g12
576-g14
576-g3
576-g48
576-g51
577-g1
579-g25
579-g9
58-g25
58-g28
58-g3
58-g30
580-g29
580-g37
580-g41
580-g49
580-g6
581-g10
581-g15
581-g4
581-g6
582-g12
582-g13
582-g21
582-g4
583-g2
583-g7
584-g4
586-g2
59-g23
59-g24
593-g3
594-g8
595-g10
596-g9
6-g3
60-g25
601-g19
601-g25
601-g4
601-g5
601-g9
602-g15
602-g25
603-g12
603-g22
604-g1
605-g7
606-g11
61-g8
62-g3
69-g11
7-g2
71-g14
71-g4
71-g5
72-g5
73-g22
73-g25
74-g19
75-g37
79-g14
79-g3
8-g1
8-g7
80-g1
82-g8
84-g10
84-g33
844-g11
85-g2
85-g27
85-g38
87-g3
87-g50
88-g16
88-g17
88-g8
9-g10
90-g9
D512-2
D564
D631-7
DDO064
DDO154
DDO161
DDO168
DDO170
DDO52
F561-1
F563-V1
F563-V2
F5631
F565-V2
F567-2
F568-1
F568-3
F568-V1
F5683
F571-8
F571-V1
F5718
F574-1
F574-2
F579-V1
F579V1
F583-1
F583-4
F5831
F5834
F730V1
Holm370
IC0382
IC0387
IC0407
IC0784
IC1330
IC1474
IC2974
IC4202
IC5078
IC5282
KK98-251
M33
MCG01-23-002
MCG01-23-013
MCG01-23-021
MCG01-25-022
MCG02-02-040
MCG02-02-051
MCG02-07-033
MCG02-13-019
MCG02-14-003
MCG02-15-006
MCG02-22-023
MCG02-22-025
MCG02-25-002
MCG03-10-042
MCG03-13-064
MCG03-16-023
MCG03-38-025
Milky_Way
NGC0024
NGC0055
NGC0100
NGC0151
NGC0247
NGC0300
NGC0697
NGC0699
NGC0701
NGC0801
NGC0891
NGC1090
NGC1114
NGC1163
NGC1241
NGC1247
NGC1337
NGC1417
NGC1421
NGC1620
NGC1705
NGC1752
NGC1832
NGC2366
NGC2403
NGC2584
NGC2683
NGC2721
NGC2722
NGC2763
NGC2903
NGC2915
NGC2955
NGC2980
NGC2998
NGC3029
NGC3138
NGC3145
NGC3198
NGC3321
NGC3361
NGC3456
NGC3521
NGC3715
NGC3726
NGC3741
NGC3769
NGC3877
NGC3893
NGC3917
NGC3949
NGC3953
NGC3972
NGC3992
NGC4010
NGC4051
NGC4085
NGC4088
NGC4100
NGC4138
NGC4157
NGC4183
NGC4214
NGC4217
NGC4348
NGC4559
NGC4705
NGC5005
NGC5033
NGC5055
NGC5371
NGC5585
NGC5907
NGC5985
NGC6015
NGC6503
NGC6789
NGC6822
NGC6946
NGC7218
NGC7300
NGC7339
NGC7536
NGC7568
NGC7591
NGC7593
NGC7631
NGC7677
NGC7793
NGC959
PGC51017
UCG00541
UGC00014
UGC00128
UGC00191
UGC00210
UGC00321
UGC00634
UGC00731
UGC00891
UGC01230
UGC01281
UGC01938
UGC02020
UGC02079
UGC02259
UGC02455
UGC02487
UGC02953
UGC03205
UGC03580
UGC04115
UGC04278
UGC04305
UGC04325
UGC04483
UGC04499
UGC05005
UGC05253
UGC05414
UGC05716
UGC05721
UGC05750
UGC05764
UGC05829
UGC05918
UGC05986
UGC05999
UGC06399
UGC06446
UGC06614
UGC06628
UGC06667
UGC06786
UGC06917
UGC06923
UGC06930
UGC06973
UGC06983
UGC07089
UGC07125
UGC07151
UGC07232
UGC07261
UGC07323
UGC07399
UGC07524
UGC07559
UGC07577
UGC07603
UGC07608
UGC07690
UGC07866
UGC08286
UGC08490
UGC08550
UGC09037
UGC09992
UGC10310
UGC11454
UGC11455
UGC11557
UGC11583
UGC11616
UGC11648
UGC11748
UGC11819
UGC11820
UGC11914
UGC12123
UGC12290
UGC12370
UGC12382
UGC12423
UGC12506
UGC12533
UGC12555
UGC12565
UGC12571
UGC12583
UGC12632
UGC12732
UGCA281
UGCA442
UGCA444
```